# Discounts doesn't match on Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I want to get the discount amount from the REST Admin API on Shopify the way they report it in their finances summary. But their API just returns some amounts that doesn't match with what they report.

[image]

Here you can see how they report **$17.01** for an item in the order, while they return **$17.86** in the API. And the same goes for the second item. That gives us a difference of **$1.47** between their report and what they return in the API.

Can someone help with that matter?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, it's being rounded at some point (see [here](https://community.shopify.com/c/Accounting-Taxes/Incorrect-application-of-discounts/td-p/452588)). If you ask how that's possible if they seem less rounded, it's probably because there are multiple items in one order

Comment: Remember to read the whole page, the actual answer is further down

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for. These guys are using a third party app to apply discounts, which made the problem occur. That's why the shopify support send a ticket for them. But about the discounts in shopify, the support said that the system doesn't round the amount up. Here's his answer : https://community.shopify.com/c/Accounting-Taxes/Incorrect-application-of-discounts/m-p/452589/highlight/true#M2181 , I quote : "Since I'm not seeing our systems rounding the discounted amount up on my end"